# How to use babel-plugin-rewire with React?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, babel-plugin, react-test-renderer

I'm seeing this error:

```
 ✖ should dispatch profileAction
      PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0)
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '_Header2.default.__Rewire__('profileAction', function (a) {
          a();
        })')
        at     /home/piousbox/Dropbox/projects/colombia_tailors_react/app/app.tests.js:74904 <- webpack:///app/components/App/__tests__/Header-test.jsx:23:53
```

My test looks like this:

```
  it('should dispatch profileAction', (done) => {
    Header.__Rewire__('profileAction', (a) => { a() })
    let r = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Header router={{location:{}}} />
      </Provider>)
    let elem = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(r)
  })
```

My production code looks like this:

```
import { profileAction } from '../../actions/profileActions'
profileAction // eslint-disable-line no-unused-expressions
class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    props.dispatch(profileAction())
  }
  render () { ... }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I am looking to assert that profileAction() was called when the component Header was mounted.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was misconfiguration of webpack, I now have this and it works:

`{
     test: /\.jsx?$/,
     exclude: /node_modules/,
-    loader: 'babel-loader?plugins=babel-plugin-rewire',
+    loader: 'babel-loader',
     query: {
-      presets: [ 'babel-preset-es2015', 'babel-preset-stage-2', 'babel-preset-react' ]
+      presets: [ 'babel-preset-es2015', 'babel-preset-stage-2', 'babel-preset-react' ],
+      plugins: [ 'babel-plugin-rewire' ],
     }
   },`

I added `{ query: { plugins: [ 'babel-plugin-rewire' ] } }` to webpack/loaders.js, and it works.